# Use git-credential-libsecret over nogui ssh-connection

Tags: linux, git

I want to use **git-credential-libsecret** in linux rhel to store git passwords so as not to ask them again and again after each pull & push.

**Setup:**
I am logging to a linux rhel VM hosted on VirtualBox
I am loggin through ssh. VM is started headless without GUI

**Problem:**
After many hours of configure & troubleshooting, when i make a git push I have the error below:

```
Cloning into 'XXX'...
** (process:3333): CRITICAL **: 12:21:55.674: secret_value_get_text: assertion 'value' failed
** (process:3333): CRITICAL **: 12:21:55.674: secret_value_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
```

Searching on journalctl, I found the error below:

```
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: Created slice User Background Tasks Slice.
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: Started dbus-:1.2-org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter@1.service.
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: Starting Cleanup of User's Temporary Files and Directories...
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: Finished Cleanup of User's Temporary Files and Directories.
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain gcr-prompter[2784]: cannot open display:
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: dbus-:1.2-org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter@1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1506]: dbus-:1.2-org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain gnome-keyring-daemon[2547]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not activate remote peer.
Oct 13 11:47:15 localhost.localdomain gnome-keyring-d[2547]: couldn't create system prompt: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not activate remote peer.
```

**Important:** At this point, if I open a GUI session for the running vm and login, then the error is no longer reproducible. Logging in from a GUI session probably unlocks the keyring and no need for display is needed from that point and on

**Question:** Do you have any idea on what I can do in order to avoid openning a GUI session to my vm just to login to unlock this keyring collection?

**Remarks:** Setting up an xserver in windows host and connecting through ssh with X-11 forwarding is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can answer my own queston after some more debugging and tests.
When a GUI session starts, keyring is unlocked:

```
Oct 13 14:30:25 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[811]: New session 4 of user XXXX.
Oct 13 14:30:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of User XXXX.
Oct 13 14:30:25 localhost.localdomain gdm-password][2622]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user XXXX(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Oct 13 14:30:25 localhost.localdomain gdm-password][2622]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
```

In order to achieve a similar behaviour through an ssh connection, **gnome-keyring-daemon** needs to be started and unlocked explicitely:

```
echo -n "$pass" | gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --unlock
```

After that, git-credential-libsecret works as expected and no password is needed anymore